# How to remove a substring from a string based on list of strings

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings(colors), say

```
l = ['chocolate brown','brown','chocolate']
```

I have a string:

```
sentence = "The jeans is chocolate brown in color and has brown colored pockets"
```

I have to remove `chocolate brown` and `brown` from the string. This is just an example. Basically whenever I encounter a color in a string I have to remove it if it exists in the list of colors. What is the efficient way to do it?

One approach that I thought was to split the string into trigrams, bigrams and unigrams. But joining these n-grams back and consistently between all n-grams would be a problem.

My original list is too huge and the string is short. I need an efficient solution since I have to loop over all the elements of the list. Is it possible if I could check the string for the color and then check if that color is in the list. Wouldn't that be an efficient solution?

Comment: so chocolate stays in the list?

Comment: Finally the string should be "The jeans is in color and has colored pockets".

Comment: `I  have to remove chocolate brown and brown from the list. `  is totally different than the above comment.

Comment: @wannaC, now you have two completely contrasting statements, is it from the list or the string?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I have updated my question. Sorry for the error.

Comment: then you just want to loop and replace iterating over the list of words

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ['chocolate brown','brown', 'chocolate']

sentence = "The jeans is chocolate brown in color and has brown colored pockets"

for word in l:
    # "word + ' '" is for deleting the trailing whitespace after each color word.
    sentence_new = sentence.replace(word + ' ', '') 
    sentence = sentence_new

print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
The jeans is in color and has colored pockets
```

Basically just replace what you don't want with what you want (I used an empty string ""), and put this action in a loop.

Note that `replace()` returns a new string instead of modifying the original string, so you have to put it into a new variable, such as str_new.

Comment: @Akavall Thanks for the comment. I changed it accordingly.

Comment: This won't be efficient when my list is huge and string is short.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> l = ['chocolate brown','brown','chocolate']
>>> s = "The jeans is chocolate brown in color and has brown colored pockets"
>>>
>>> re.sub('|'.join(re.escape(r) for r in l), '', s)
'The jeans is  in color and has  colored pockets'
```